# Accepting multiple connections on a boost asio tcp socket

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-asio

## I want to accept twice on one socket

That is, I listen on a port (an unconnected socket) and want to get two connected sockets in the end.

Said differently, if I accept twice on the same tcp socket, I'm having trouble grokking how to distinguish between the two connected sockets in asio.  This is on linux.

I have a relatively simple tcp server class.  It assumes that all clients that might connect to it are homogeneous: if a message is waiting to go to a client and none is connected, it can be sent to the next client that does connect.  This works great with one connected socket, but now I need to listen on more than one socket (that is, two clients will connect).  The homogeneity assumption is still almost true, but now I have the additional constraint that if a message is in response to someone, it should go to that someone.  (Replies are often acknowledgements.)

I start by listening and accepting:

```
short port = kSomethingKnown;
boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_(io_service_);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_(
    io_service_,
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [this](boost::system::error_code ec) {
    if (ec) {
        // Failed to accept.  Schedule to try again (not shown).
        return;
    }
    // Accepted.
    SendMessage();   // Flush any old messages, appropriate with a single client.
    ReceiveHeader();
});
```

## Comparison to the BSD socket interface

I'll explain the rest below, but this illustrates the main point.  ACCEPT(2) looks like this:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

The return value, if non-zero, is the file descriptor of the connected socket.  That is, if I'm on host H and listening on port P, then `sockfd` represents an unconnected socket,

```
(H, P, tcp, 0, 0)
```

and the file descriptor returned represents a connected socket,

```
(H, P, tcp, H1, P1)
```

where H1 is the client host and P1 is the (probably ephemeral) port on the client that is the other side of this socket.  If I successfully accept a second time, I'll get another connected socket,

```
(H, P, tcp, H2, P2)
```

where at least one of H2 and P2 is different than H1 and P1.  I don't see in asio how to refer to these two connected sockets.  I've been reading source code, which is teaching me a great deal about how asio works but not how `async_accept` works.

## Ancillary details

Fwiw, here are the details on the send and receive calls, but I think the above is what I really need.  Once I understand that, then I use those connected sockets instead of `socket_`.

`SendMessage()` exists in a form that takes a message (just pushes it on a deque) and the form above that processes the queue.  That second form looks like this:

```
void SendMessage() {
    if (WeAreDead()) {
        // This checked that the connection seems valid,
        // we aren't being asked to shut down, etc.
        return;
    }
    if (send_queue_.empty()) {
        // Nothing to send.
        return;
    }
    boost::asio::async_write(
        socket_, boost::asio::buffer(send_queue_.front()),
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t length) {
            if (ec) {
                // Failed, schedule another attempt, not shown here.
                return;
            }
            send_queue_.pop_front();
            if (!send_queue_.empty()) {
                SendMessage();
            }
        });
}
```

The `ReceiveHeader()` (and a similar `ReceiveBody()`) look similar, with the key bit being a call that looks like this:

```
boost::asio::async_read(
    socket_, boost::asio::buffer(receive_buffer_, kTcpHeaderSize),
    boost::asio::transfer_exactly(kTcpHeaderSize),
    [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t received_length) {
```

Again, the part that I'm finding confusing is related to `async_accept()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    acceptor_.async_accept(
    [this] (std::error_code ec, tcp::socket&& new_socket) {
```

In this case you get a `new_socket` object, which represents the accepted connection. I have taken it from this [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp).

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's precisely what I misunderstood about `async_accept()`: the socket I pass it is a _returned_ value, not the unconnected socket on which I want to accept.  I'll need to play with this for a bit to confirm that I understand.  (I'm also a bit uncertain about ownership of the provided socket, since you indicate an rvalue.)

Comment: To be fair, older versions didn't have this option, and `socket` was to be passed in. Indeed, the move would have to be done later / the socket would have to be allocated dynamically: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp. Accepting an rvalue makes the ownership clear as day: it can't be anything other than transferring ownership